# Can't get the values of my table (getElementById not working)

Tags: javascript, php, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get a line of a  dynamic table once the " reserver" button is clicked (or the line itself is clicked 'if that matters')but the 'getElementById' doesn't return anything ( i want to display them in an input)
here is the code

**HTML / PHP**

```
<div class="form1">
            <div>
            <label>Code creneau1</label>
            <input type="text" id="nop" name='nop'>
            <label>Code creneau2</label>
            <input type="text" id="seh" name='seh'>
            <label>Code creneau3</label>
            <input type="text" id="row" name='row'>
            <label>Code creneau4</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name='name'>
            
            </div>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="res">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>code salle</th>
                <th> type </th>
                <th>etage</th>
                <th>capacité</th>
                <th> action</th>
                
                
            </tr>
        </thead> 
 <tbody><?php
        while ($donnees = $requete->fetch() and $donnees2 = $requete2->fetch())
                 {
                    $donnees_ar=$_POST['date'];
                    $code_cr=$_POST['heure'];
                // echo $donnees2['id_res'].'<br>';
              
            
                 if($donnees['code_salle']!=$donnees2['code_salle'] and $donnees2['date_res']=$_POST['date']){
 echo "<tr id='try'>

                <td >".$donnees['code_salle']."</td>
                <td >".$donnees['type_salle']."</td>
                <td >".$donnees['capacity']."</td>
                <td >".$donnees['etage']."</td>
                
                <td>
                  <a href='#0' id='he' class='cd-popup-trigger'>reserver</a>
                </td> 
            </tr>";
          }
        }; 
      }
         ?>
```

**the JS**

```
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   <script>
        var tbl= document.getElementById("res");
        for(var x=1;x<tbl.rows.length;x++ ){
            tbl.rows[x].onclick =function {
               document.getElementById('name').value=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
               document.getElementById('row').value=this.cells[1].innerHTML;
               document.getElementById('seh').value=this.cells[2].innerHTML;
               document.getElementById("nop").value=this.cells[3].innerHTML;

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: "_'getElementById' doesn't return anyhting_" Not possible, the said method returns either a reference to an element or `null`. Make sure not to run the code before the elements exist, and that `this` in your code refers to a correct element (I doubt it isn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been declared the JavaScript inside the JS file itself. in this case, The JS file Won't run for your HTML and won't affect anything written in your HTML. Also, you have declared your onClick function in the wrong way. To do this, you need to move the  tag inside your HTML. For a better demonstration:

```js
var table= document.getElementById("res");

if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
            tableText(this);
        };
    }
}

function tableText(tableCell) {
    alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="form1">
            <div>
            <label>Code creneau1</label>
            <input type="text" id="nop" name='nop'>
            <label>Code creneau2</label>
            <input type="text" id="seh" name='seh'>
            <label>Code creneau3</label>
            <input type="text" id="row" name='row'>
            <label>Code creneau4</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name='name'>
            
            </div>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="res">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>code salle</th>
                <th> type </th>
                <th>etage</th>
                <th>capacité</th>
                <th> action</th>
                
                
            </tr>
        </thead> 
 <tbody>
 <?php
        while ($donnees = $requete->fetch() and $donnees2 = $requete2->fetch())
                 {
                    $donnees_ar=$_POST['date'];
                    $code_cr=$_POST['heure'];
                // echo $donnees2['id_res'].'<br>';
              
            
                 if($donnees['code_salle']!=$donnees2['code_salle'] and $donnees2['date_res']=$_POST['date']){
 echo "<tr id='try'>

                <td >".$donnees['code_salle']."</td>
                <td >".$donnees['type_salle']."</td>
                <td >".$donnees['capacity']."</td>
                <td >".$donnees['etage']."</td>
                
                <td>
                  <a href='#0' id='he' class='cd-popup-trigger'>reserver</a>
                </td> 
            </tr>";
          }
        }; 
      }
         ?>
```

Comment: My JS is in the HTML file and is the last thing on the page ( it's not in a separate file) and i don't click on the line until the html and php R done  and still nothing is working @ShayanFaghani

Comment: Dear @OumniaRanaSEGUENI 

I don't know about the exact functionality, but if you need to change something you can use the above-edited code. It will alert the cell that has been clicked.

You can add your own functionality to it as you desire.

Comment: Was it a solution for you?

Comment: thank you it worked ! although now i'm stuck trying to transfer it  form Js to php but your code worked so thanks again